# Sharing a FILE pointer between libraries

Tags: c, file, io, fopen, stdio

I got a simple quesiton; I am using a `FILE* fp` in one of my libraries to `fopen/fwrite` to the file, and I want to do `fclose()` on `fp` in another library - what is the best way for the other library to get the file handle?

Comment: Generally it is considered a best practice to handle the opening and closing of a file at the same level in the same context/task. Same with memory allocation/deallocation. (But you might have specific requirements in your case)

Comment: that's a strange requirement; strange requirements are often (thought not always) an indication of incorrect design or solving a problem the wrong way.

Comment: Do both libraries use the same runtime?

Answer (score 6):

If your two libraries talk to each other then the first should pass the `FILE*` to the second in a function call.

If the libraries don't talk to each other then the main application should get the `FILE*` from the first library and hand it to the second library. Or better, the application should own the `FILE*`, hand it to the first library already opened, and then hand it to the second library to be finished off, and finally the application should close the `FILE*` itself. Trying to deal with a library that wants a filename instead of a `FILE*` can be very frustrating when you have something that is like a file but doesn't have a name.